# Creating a variable amount of linked lists for hashmap

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, hashtable

Here are the important parts of my code with unhelpful portions commented out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "hmap.h"

struct val_word{
char *final_word;
struct val_word* next;
};


int main (int argc, char **argv){

  //Check if dictionary file is given 

  FILE *fp1;
  char key [125];
  char val [125];
  char temp;
  struct val_word *storage;
  char c;
  int i;
  int j;
  int l;


  HMAP_PTR dictionary = hmap_create(0, 0.75);

  fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  do{
    c = fscanf(fp1, "%s", key);


    // Convert string to lowercase

    strcpy(val, key);

    //Alphabetically sort string


    struct val_word* word_node = malloc(sizeof(struct val_word));
    word_node->final_word = val;
    word_node->next = NULL;

    storage = hmap_get(dictionary, key);


    if(storage == NULL){
        hmap_set(dictionary, key, word_node);
    }
    else{
        struct val_word *temp2 = storage;

        while(temp2->next != NULL){
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }

        word_node->final_word = val;
        word_node->next = NULL;

        temp2->next = word_node;

        hmap_set(dictionary, key, storage);

    }


  } while (c != EOF);

  fclose(fp1);

  while(storage->next != NULL){
    printf("The list is %s\n", storage->final_word);
    storage = storage->next;
  }


  return 0;

}
```

I am given a dictionary file of unknown length, as well as a hash table implementation file that I cannot touch. The hash table stores jumbled versions of words, with the key being the alphabetically sorted version of the word. For example:

Part of the dictionary contains: leloh, hello, elloh, holel

**key** would be: ehllo

**val** would be a linked list storing the aforementioned 4 words.

hmap_get gets the value at the given key, and hmap_set sets the value at the given key.

My code processes everything fine, until I try to print the list located at a key.
The list will be of the correct size, but only stores the **LAST value** that it took as input. So adding onto the example above, my list would be (in chronological order):

1. leloh
2. elloh -> elloh
3. holel -> holel -> holel
4. ehllo -> ehllo -> ehllo -> ehllo

For some reason it also stores the correctly alphabetized string as the last string, which I did not provide the hmap_set function. Very confused about that.

However, the list makes perfect sense. I only have one node, and it is inside of a for loop. I do not change the variable name and therefore the pointers all point to the same node, and the node changes the string it contains through every iteration of the loop.

So, I am wondering how I would fix this. 
I can't dynamically name variables, I can't just create a dynamic array of linked lists because I feel like that would defeat the purpose of having the hash table.
I don't know what sort of data type I would use to store this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Using a `do … while` loop like that is bad.  Use `while (fscanf(fp1, "%s", key) == 1)` as a `while` loop instead.  Your code runs through the loop with the last line repeated when you reach EOF.  That's not really a good idea.

Comment: The problem is, I think, that you keep reading new values into `val` (copying from `key`), but you only have one variable.  You need to duplicate the strings before stashing them in your hash map.  So, look up the `strdup()` function and make a copy of the string in `key` using `strdup()` instead of `strcpy()`.  Assign the value returned from `strdup()` to `word_node->final_word`.  If you're not allowed to use `strdup`, write your own variant: `char *dup_str(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str) + 1; char *dup = malloc(len); if (dup != 0) memmove(dup, str, len); return dup; }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yup, I wish you would have submitted it as answer so I could select it, but thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer — where the code is easier to read.*</sup>

The problem is, I think, that you keep reading new values into `val` (copying from `key`), but you only have one variable.

You need to duplicate the strings before stashing them in your hash map. So, look up the [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) function and make a copy of the string in `key` using `strdup()` instead of `strcpy()`. Assign the value returned from `strdup()` to `word_node->final_word`.

If you're not allowed to use `strdup()`, write your own variant:

```
char *dup_str(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *dup = malloc(len);
    if (dup != 0)
        memmove(dup, str, len);
    return dup;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It's interesting to see the difference between the duplicate and the copy. I thought I was being foolproof by using strcpy! Thank you!

Comment: Could also be done with memcpy(), memmove() is not needed here: the strings *cannot* overlap.

Comment: @joop: I use `memmove()` so I don't have to remember when it is OK and not OK to use `memcpy()`.  You're right, but simplicity is beneficial in my view.

Comment: But it is confusing to beginners, IMHO. And non-beginners should *know* when  memory objects can / cannot overlap. (and there is also the (silly) performance argument)

Comment: What's confusing to beginners?  That there are two functions for a single job?  Yes; it is ludicrous.  Therefore, I use the one that works regardless, so that beginners can't get it wrong.  The spurious (or mostly spurious) efficiency argument isn't worth using — it confuses beginners.  So, "use `memmove()` because it always works" is simpler for beginners than the weasel-wording needed to cover `memcpy()`.  AFAIAC, `memcpy()` doesn't exist except as a trap for beginners, rather like `gets()` and `strtok()` and `sprintf()` and … don't exist (sorta — `gets()` counts as a core dump in my book).

Comment: BTW: you forgot strncpy() and strcat().

Comment: Oh, yes — and `strncat()` which you can't use safely unless you have enough information not to need to use it at all!